# How to create one function to insert a word when I click on it in Angular .kendo context menu

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-menu

I'm having trouble figuring out how I'm going to be able to insert a word when  click on it from the context menu, my code is this :  public items:
component.ts

```
<html>
<a> any[] = [
      {
        text: "hello",
        items: [{ text: "Item1.1" }, { text: "Item1.2" }],
      },
      {
        text: "Item2",
        
      },
      {
        text: "hello2",
      }] </a></html>
```

and my context menu : [image]

I wanted, for example, to press hello2 and it would write where I clicked with the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

When you define your items in the component's typescript file, assign the `data` property to the value you wish to insert. Then declare a function that gets the item:

```js
items: any[] = [
  {
    text: 'hello',
    items: [
      {
        data: 'Item1.1',
        text: "Item1.1"
      },
      {
        data: 'Item1.2',
        text: "Item1.2"
      }
    ],
    // etc...
];

function menuSelect(e: any): void {
  const data = e.item?.data;
  console.log(data); // do something with data
}
```

Then when you define your `kendo-menu`, bind the `items` property ([documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/menus/api/MenuComponent/#toc-items)) to respective variable and the `menuSelectEvent` ([documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/menus/api/MenuSelectEvent/)) to the respective function:

```html
<kendo-menu [items]="items" (select)="menuSelect($event)">
</kendo-menu>
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Do you know any way now with this word to insert in the text editor I have?

Comment: @ClaudioGuedes - What text editor component are you using?

Comment: https://codemirror.net/ in angular

Comment: @ClaudioGuedes - I'm not familiar with that component. Looking at the API documentation, I would suggestion calling the getCursor method to get the character index of where the right-click was pressed: https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#getCursor combined with getValue and setValue to set the text.

Comment: ok I will try, thanks for the help